# mysql how to check if there are any rows with partial key value most efficiently

Tags: mysql, select, explain

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `offline_data` (
  `od_sid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `od_email_hash` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `od_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `od_pur_time` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `od_order_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `od_products` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `od_attributes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  `od_userinfo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `od_pids_type` enum('pid_orig','platform_id') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'pid_orig',
  PRIMARY KEY (`od_sid`,`od_email_hash`,`od_order_id`),
  KEY `site_time` (`od_sid`,`od_pur_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (od_sid) PARTITIONS 30 */;
```

I want to know if there are any items with od_sid = 23957 ;

explain  SELECT count(*) FROM offline_data WHERE od_sid=23957 
gives:
1   SIMPLE  offline_data    ref PRIMARY,site_time   site_time   4   const   23  Using index

explain  SELECT 1 FROM offline_data WHERE od_sid=23957 ORDER BY od_pur_time DESC LIMIT 1; 
gives:
1   SIMPLE  offline_data    ref PRIMARY,site_time   site_time   4   const   23  Using where; Using index

explain  SELECT 1 FROM offline_data WHERE od_sid=23957 LIMIT 1; 
gives: 1    SIMPLE  offline_data    ref PRIMARY,site_time   site_time   4   const   23  Using index

In all cases there is a scan of 23 rows (thats the table size now, it will grow to 10,000,000 s).
How can I do the check without scanning of rows?

Comment: I would not give too much about that EXPLAIN output column: *The rows column indicates the number of rows MySQL believes it must examine to execute the query.

For InnoDB tables, this number is an estimate, and may not always be exact.* The index is used and the result is probably super fast, even with millions of records

Comment: I would also add that having a table with 23 records might not behave the same as one with millions of records.  MySQL might not even use the index for a very small table, if it determines that a full table scan would be faster.